# Why does java Ethereum use UDP? - isn't devp2p TCP only

Tags: network, devp2p

Looking through the source code for java ethereum I see *[UDPListener](https://github.com/ethereum/ethereumj/blob/f82a1fbbb104b43502685ad308891bcce8e74c49/ethereumj-core/src/main/java/org/ethereum/net/rlpx/discover/UDPListener.java)* is part of the *org.ethereum.net.rlpx.discover* package and that this seems to use NioDatagramChannel (Netty's way of handling UDP datagrams) to handle Ping, Pong, FindNode and Neighbours messages and do the kademia DHT stuff. However the [Devp2p specs](https://ethereum.gitbooks.io/frontier-guide/content/devp2p.html) say it is TCP only and indeed TCP is used for communication once nodes are discovered.

So I'm slightly confused; is UDP officially used for node discovery and then TCP for communication and if so where is this node discovery protocol documented?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Q**: is UDP officially used for node discovery and then TCP for communication?

Yes.

You can see the 30301 UDP discovery port in the enode URL format (from [enode url format](https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/enode-url-format)):

```
enode://6f8a...d92a0@10.3.58.6:30303?discport=30301
```

**Q**: if so where is this node discovery protocol documented?

At https://github.com/ethereum/devp2p/blob/master/rlpx.md .