# geth does not sync out of the box

Tags: go-ethereum, synchronization, ubuntu

I have a fresh new installation of Ubuntu 16.04 and I've followed manual to setup geth

```
sudo apt-get install software-properties-common
sudo add-apt-repository -y ppa:ethereum/ethereum
sudo add-apt-repository -y ppa:ethereum/ethereum-dev
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install ethereum
```

And after starting geth it hangs up on

```
I0925 07:53:21.655924 node/node.go:308] IPC endpoint opened: /home/username/.ethereum/geth.ipc
I0925 07:53:21.656651 p2p/server.go:576] Listening on [::]:30303
```

0 peers, nothing happens, no syncing. htop shows occasional activity in CPU, console answers but shows 0 peers:

```
geth attach
Welcome to the Geth JavaScript console!

instance: Geth/v1.5.0-unstable/linux/go1.6.2
coinbase: 0x4c49eed9cc104695593cd2a9745ce108e28efc09
at block: 0 (Thu, 01 Jan 1970 03:00:00 MSK)
 datadir: /home/username/.ethereum
 modules: admin:1.0 debug:1.0 eth:1.0 miner:1.0 net:1.0 personal:1.0 rpc:1.0 txpool:1.0 web3:1.0

> net.listening
true
> net.peerCount
0
```

Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## The `geth` Bootnodes Are Down

I've tested, and the peer discovery nodes are intermittently / mostly down.

---

## Update 08:19 Sep 25 2016

I suspect that the bootnodes are congested due to the many `geth` clients trying to get connections as the clients are being restarted due to the recent memory bug attack and spam / IO transaction attacks.

`telnet` is able to intermittently connect to some of the bootnodes, but `geth` has been unable to find any peers for over an hour.

A separate `geth` node I started many hours ago is working fine with 25 peer connections.

I have checked the blockhash for the latest block I have synced up to and it matches etherscan.io [#2,287,735](https://etherscan.io/block/2287735):

```
> admin.peers
[]
> eth.blockNumber
2287735
> eth.getBlock(eth.blockNumber).hash
"0x53a331f2c93a796170e3af16f66b998fd0ed5acb8caccb79c2431e111b67419b"
```

[image]

---

## Update 23:17 Sep 25 2016

@jamiepitts-ethereum in [reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/ethereum/comments/54ec53/ethereum_wallet_geth_client_not_syncing_possible/d81h7hi) said

> Please test this now and reply whether peers are found and the sync begins for you.
>
> In geth 1.4.12, I am now able to find peers and successfully start syncing.

I've tested and my previously non-syncing node now syncs automatically. I retested connectivity to the bootnodes below and the first 3 connect immediately.

It would be interesting to know what caused this non-syncing situation for many `geth` nodes. Update the node software on their bootnode servers? Reboot their bootnode servers? Make available more connection slots on their bootnode server?

---

## Update 12:09 Sep 26 2016

There is a new version of `geth` named **Geth 1.4.13: Into the Woods (various DoS fixes)** that you can download from https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/releases/tag/v1.4.13 .

The .zip files with the source code and some of the different operating systems version have been made available from this page. Download the version appropriate to your operating system (if it is there, or else wait until it is available).

The Ubuntu ppa now contains `http://ppa.launchpad.net/ethereum/ethereum/ubuntu/ trusty/main bootnode amd64 1.4.13+87trusty-0ubuntu1` with this new version, so just update your ubuntu installation to pick up the new version.

This version should sync to other peers (problem fixed in the last update), but should process the I/O spam transactions much quicker compared to version 1.4.12 .

---

## Temporary Workaround

See [How can I extract create a list of peers from my syncing geth node to manually paste into my non-syncing geth node using the admin.addPeer() command?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/8828/how-can-i-extract-create-a-list-of-peers-from-my-syncing-geth-node-to-manually-p) for a list of `admin.addPeer(...)` commands you can paste into your `geth` console to kick-start your node syncing.

---

## My Tests

**Update 13:51 Oct 01 2016**
Note that the following test are not definitive as the bootnodes normally operated using the UDP protocol on port 30301, but I used the TCP 30303 for my testing. See [Why does java Ethereum use UDP? - isn't devp2p TCP only](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/3946/1268) and [What is an Enode ID in Ethereum?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/1178/1268).

Checking `geth` version

```
user@Kumquat:~$ geth version
Geth
Version: 1.4.12-stable
Protocol Versions: [63 62]
Network Id: 1
Go Version: go1.5.1
OS: linux
GOPATH=/home/user/go
GOROOT=/usr/lib/go
```

The `geth` bootnodes are listed in https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/blob/master/cmd/utils/bootnodes.go#L25-L30 and are:

```
discover.MustParseNode("enode://a979...163c@52.16.188.185:30303"), // IE
discover.MustParseNode("enode://de47...c786@54.94.239.50:30303"),  // BR
discover.MustParseNode("enode://1118...5082@52.74.57.123:30303"),  // SG

// ETH/DEV Cpp Bootnodes
discover.MustParseNode("enode://979b...37f9@5.1.83.226:30303"),
```

Testing the first server:

```
user@Kumquat:~$ telnet 52.16.188.185 30303
Trying 52.16.188.185...
telnet: Unable to connect to remote host: Connection timed out
```

Testing the second server:

```
user@Kumquat:~$ telnet 54.94.239.50 30303
Trying 54.94.239.50...
telnet: Unable to connect to remote host: Connection timed out
```

Testing the third server:

```
user@Kumquat:~$ telnet 52.74.57.123 30303
Trying 52.74.57.123...
telnet: Unable to connect to remote host: Connection timed out
```

Testing the fourth server:

```
bok@Kumquat:~$ telnet 5.1.83.226 30303
Trying 5.1.83.226...
telnet: Unable to connect to remote host: Connection refused
```

---

## Expected Results As Demonstrated On The Testnet Bootnode Servers

This is not the normal response for the bootnode servers. Here is the bootnode server for Testnet, listed in https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/blob/master/cmd/utils/bootnodes.go#L37-L38:

```
discover.MustParseNode("enode://e453...d6b8@94.242.229.4:40404"),
discover.MustParseNode("enode://8c33...4592@94.242.229.203:30303"),
```

The second bootnode server is responding as expected, not the first:

```
user@Kumquat:~$ telnet 94.242.229.4 40404
Trying 94.242.229.4...
telnet: Unable to connect to remote host: Connection refused

user@Kumquat:~$ telnet 94.242.229.203 30303
Trying 94.242.229.203...
Connected to 94.242.229.203.
Escape character is '^]'.
Connection closed by foreign host.
```

Comment: thanks, sync started. Should I expect that bootnodes will go up some time in future?))  Because Ive got only one peer in this way.