# Geth 1.4.12 not finding any peers on Ubuntu 16.04 LTS

Tags: go-ethereum, ubuntu

I am trying Linux for the first time and try to run Geth 1.4.12 but it can not find any peers.

UPnP works fine, the clock sets itself correctly and the firewall is disabled.

Do you have any idea what should I do?

Thanks

I try to run `geth --fast --verbosity 6`. Here is the console log:

```
I0925 16:55:52.656800 p2p/server.go:556] Listening on [::]:30303
I0925 16:55:52.657545 p2p/server.go:430] new task: discovery lookup
I0925 16:55:52.657902 node/node.go:296] IPC endpoint opened: /home/d1v1d4v1d/.ethereum/geth.ipc
I0925 16:55:52.659738 release/release.go:116] Release oracle not found at fa7b9770ca4cb04296cac84f37736d4041251cdf
I0925 16:55:52.664050 p2p/discover/database.go:183] failed to retrieve node a979fb575495b8d6db44f750317d0f4622bf4c2aa3365d6af7c284339968eef29b69ad0dce72a4d8db5ebb4968de0e3bec910127f134779fbcb0cb6d3331163c: leveldb: not found
I0925 16:55:52.665334 p2p/discover/table.go:473] Bonding a979fb575495b8d6: known=false, fails=0 age=409670h55m52.665323259s
I0925 16:55:52.666259 p2p/discover/udp.go:453] >>> 52.16.188.185:30303 discover.ping
I0925 16:55:52.664050 p2p/discover/database.go:183] failed to retrieve node 979b7fa28feeb35a4741660a16076f1943202cb72b6af70d327f053e248bab9ba81760f39d0701ef1d8f89cc1fbd2cacba0710a12cd5314d5e0c9021aa3637f9: leveldb: not found
I0925 16:55:52.666484 p2p/discover/table.go:473] Bonding 979b7fa28feeb35a: known=false, fails=0 age=409670h55m52.6664752s
I0925 16:55:52.667544 p2p/discover/udp.go:453] >>> 5.1.83.226:30303 discover.ping
I0925 16:55:52.664157 p2p/discover/database.go:183] failed to retrieve node de471bccee3d042261d52e9bff31458daecc406142b401d4cd848f677479f73104b9fdeb090af9583d3391b7f10cb2ba9e26865dd5fca4fcdc0fb1e3b723c786: leveldb: not found
I0925 16:55:52.667727 p2p/discover/table.go:473] Bonding de471bccee3d0422: known=false, fails=0 age=409670h55m52.66771807s
I0925 16:55:52.668256 p2p/discover/udp.go:453] >>> 54.94.239.50:30303 discover.ping
I0925 16:55:52.664195 p2p/discover/database.go:183] failed to retrieve node 1118980bf48b0a3640bdba04e0fe78b1add18e1cd99bf22d53daac1fd9972ad650df52176e7c7d89d1114cfef2bc23a2959aa54998a46afcf7d91809f0855082: leveldb: not found
I0925 16:55:52.668411 p2p/discover/table.go:473] Bonding 1118980bf48b0a36: known=false, fails=0 age=409670h55m52.668402743s
I0925 16:55:52.668917 p2p/discover/udp.go:453] >>> 52.74.57.123:30303 discover.ping
I0925 16:55:52.733620 p2p/nat/nat.go:111] mapped network port udp:30303 -> 30303 (ethereum discovery) using UPNP IGDv1-IP1
I0925 16:55:52.861670 p2p/nat/nat.go:111] mapped network port tcp:30303 -> 30303 (ethereum p2p) using UPNP IGDv1-IP1
I0925 16:55:53.169090 p2p/discover/table.go:389] no seed nodes found
I0925 16:55:53.169184 p2p/server.go:469] <-taskdone: discovery lookup
```

Answer (score 1):

The Ethereum bootnodes may be experiencing a DDoS attack. See [geth does not sync out of the box](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/8823/geth-does-not-syncs-out-of-the-box) which is a similar issue.

The solution is to manually add your peers as a temporary workaround - see [How can I extract create a list of peers from my syncing geth node to manually paste into my non-syncing geth node using the admin.addPeer() command?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/8828/how-can-i-extract-create-a-list-of-peers-from-my-syncing-geth-node-to-manually-p) .

More details can be found on [reddit/r/ethereum - Ethereum Wallet `geth` Client Not Syncing - Possible Problems With Bootnodes](https://www.reddit.com/r/ethereum/comments/54ec53/ethereum_wallet_geth_client_not_syncing_possible/).

No doubt the Ethereum devs will find a more resilient peer discovery mechanism to withstand this sort of issues.