# How to run your own bootstrap node in Ethereum?

Tags: go-ethereum, nodes

How do I run my own bootstrap node? I mean how do I make my geth only provide peers information not the blockchain. And also how does geth know whether a node is a bootstrap node or regular node? Becz without knowing the difference geth will start requesting the blockchain to the bootstrap node.

The command line option `bootnodes` let's us add bootstrap nodes and the JavaScript `addPeer`method let's us add regular nodes. So if I add a regular node using `bootnodes` than won't my geth instance request the blockchain from the bootnode?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The executable to run a bootnode is `bootnode`. In Ubuntu, this installed alongside `/usr/bin/geth` in `/usr/bin/bootnode`.

You will have to generate a key to run your bootnode:

```
user@Kumquat:/tmp$ bootnode -genkey nodekeyfile
user@Kumquat:/tmp$ cat nodekeyfile 
3bed8e0fa771475049cddac0fcc20a6cf1005e271e2b12ef339f213218b2dbdb
user@Kumquat:/tmp$ bootnode -nodekey nodekeyfile 
I1001 23:17:42.874776 p2p/discover/udp.go:217] Listening, enode://d3b75b24a4fd718b1358d28ba576b2e98f73a7465326c4504f21cc0d124466a91919de18fb72a634f9108f0eedd5ef943aea5c250b41c974c4a7fb7c159b9968@[::]:30301
```

In a separate window, I ran the `netstat` command to view the UDP 30301 port that `bootnode` is listening on:

```
user@Kumquat:/tmp$ sudo netstat -anp | grep boot
[sudo] password for user: 
udp6       0      0 :::30301                :::*                                8317/bootnode
```

This `bootnode` program only serves as a bootstrapping node and will not provide any blockchain data transfers.

You should now be able to use `enode://d3b75b24a4fd718b1358d28ba576b2e98f73a7465326c4504f21cc0d124466a91919de18fb72a634f9108f0eedd5ef943aea5c250b41c974c4a7fb7c159b9968@[::]:30301` as your `geth --bootnodes` parameter value, where you replace `[::]` with the IP address of your bootnode computer.

---

## Update

If you have issues getting the peer-to-peer discovery to work, add the `--verbosity 6` before the `console` parameter of `geth`. You should see the communications to the bootnode in action.

You can also add the verbosity parameter to the `bootnode` command:

```
user@Kumquat:/tmp$ bootnode -nodekey nodekeyfile -verbosity 9
I1001 23:17:42.874776 p2p/discover/udp.go:217] Listening, enode://d3b75b24a4fd718b1358d28ba576b2e98f73a7465326c4504f21cc0d124466a91919de18fb72a634f9108f0eedd5ef943aea5c250b41c974c4a7fb7c159b9968@[::]:30301
I1001 23:39:12.546003 p2p/discover/udp.go:453] >>> 192.168.1.14:54991 discover.pong
I1001 23:39:12.546145 p2p/discover/udp.go:521] <<< 192.168.1.14:54991 *discover.ping: ok
I1001 23:39:12.546226 p2p/discover/database.go:183] failed to retrieve node b68ed408e685e6dc75ea457b65f945fa2c6f2171c8bfaf26e32d6362c3ebe9ed3ef3aeb682991e3a01250f93f2a68ea8ca1a98676e669cc007ed227c35d7c3f1: leveldb: not found
I1001 23:39:12.546337 p2p/discover/table.go:473] Bonding b68ed408e685e6dc: known=false, fails=0 age=409813h39m12.54632801s
I1001 23:39:12.547012 p2p/discover/udp.go:453] >>> 192.168.1.14:54991 discover.ping
I1001 23:39:12.549582 p2p/discover/udp.go:521] <<< 192.168.1.14:54991 *discover.pong: ok
I1001 23:39:12.556974 p2p/discover/udp.go:453] >>> 192.168.1.14:54991 discover.neighbors
I1001 23:39:12.557059 p2p/discover/udp.go:521] <<< 192.168.1.14:54991 *discover.findnode: ok
```

And the latest P2P discovery protocol documentation can be found at [RLPx: Cryptographic Network & Transport Protocol](https://github.com/ethereum/devp2p/blob/master/rlpx.md).

Comment: I think the devp2p protocol is missing the capabilities info. I think the node should declare if it is bootnode or not.