# Node discovery: unreachable bootnode in private distributed network

Tags: private-blockchain, docker, node-discovery, bootnodes

I am trying to create a private distributed network using Docker containers on Virtual Machines running ubuntu.

When I run:

```
bootnode --genkey $KEY_FILE --writeaddress
bootnode --nodekey $KEY_FILE --addr :30301 --nat extip:$MY_IP
```

either on the docker container (exposing ports `8454`, `30303`, `30301:30301` and `30301:30301/udp`) or outside of it, if I run `telnet <VM-BOOTNODE-IP> 30301` I get `telnet: Unable to connect to remote host: Connection refused` as reponse. If I create the bootnode NOT on a docker container `sudo netstat -tulpn | grep 30301` responds with

```
udp6       0      0 :::30301          :::*                      */bootnode
```

However, when I create in the container mapping the ports `sudo netstat -tulpn | grep 30301` responds with

```
tcp6       0      0 :::30301          :::*          LISTEN      */docker-proxy 
udp6       0      0 :::30301          :::*                      */docker-proxy
```

Either way I get the same "Unable to connect to remote host" error with telnet. I believe it is because the bootnode's address is unreachable that the other nodes cannot be discovered.

Just to be clear: I am using the same genesis file with a particular `networkId` and `GEN_NONCE` on all VMs. My nodes are using `--nodiscover` (discovery port = 0) and they are listening on `30303`. Using verbose level 9 on the bootnode container shows no ping/pong as suggested [here](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/8953/how-to-run-your-own-bootstrap-node-in-ethereum/8955#8955).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, apparently the reason why the connection is being refused is that "['Connection refused' is ok for the Go bootnode. [as i]t does not accept TCP connections](https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/issues/380)", as suggested by fjl in the go-ethereum issue 380

Discovery uses UDP as protocol. If you want to test if it's working properly, use `netcat -u -z -v <PUB-IP> 30301` instead.