# Geth v1.7.2 not connecting to peers on ropsten?

Tags: go-ethereum, ropsten

I'm using `geth` from `Ethereum Wallet` (as you can tell from the command path).

```
$ '/home/myalias/.config/Ethereum Wallet/binaries/Geth/unpacked/geth' console --testnet --datadir=/home/rshi/.ropsten --port 30304 --syncmode fast --cache 1024 --rpc --rpcaddr "localhost" --rpcport 8545 --rpccorsdomain "*"
WARN [01-17|12:01:54] No etherbase set and no accounts found as default
INFO [01-17|12:01:54] Starting peer-to-peer node               instance=Geth/v1.7.2-stable-1db4ecdc/linux-amd64/go1.9
INFO [01-17|12:01:54] Allocated cache and file handles         database=/home/rshi/.ropsten/geth/chaindata cache=1024 handles=1024
INFO [01-17|12:01:54] Initialised chain configuration          config="{ChainID: 3 Homestead: 0 DAO: <nil> DAOSupport: true EIP150: 0 EIP155: 10 EIP158: 10 Byzantium: 1700000 Engine: ethash}"
INFO [01-17|12:01:54] Disk storage enabled for ethash caches   dir=/home/rshi/.ropsten/geth/ethash count=3
INFO [01-17|12:01:54] Disk storage enabled for ethash DAGs     dir=/home/rshi/.ethash              count=2
INFO [01-17|12:01:54] Initialising Ethereum protocol           versions="[63 62]" network=3
INFO [01-17|12:01:54] Loaded most recent local header          number=0 hash=419410…ca4a2d td=1048576
INFO [01-17|12:01:54] Loaded most recent local full block      number=0 hash=419410…ca4a2d td=1048576
INFO [01-17|12:01:54] Loaded most recent local fast block      number=0 hash=419410…ca4a2d td=1048576
INFO [01-17|12:01:54] Loaded local transaction journal         transactions=0 dropped=0
INFO [01-17|12:01:54] Regenerated local transaction journal    transactions=0 accounts=0
INFO [01-17|12:01:54] Starting P2P networking
INFO [01-17|12:01:56] UDP listener up                          self=enode://9bceb78553d8f88bc2880754488c316c95b36246db0fc1bee64133362b045b816a5158740471d167404a84495a74cb2bf7b18944cefb2281af6b29db11fcadbf@[::]:30304
INFO [01-17|12:01:56] RLPx listener up                         self=enode://9bceb78553d8f88bc2880754488c316c95b36246db0fc1bee64133362b045b816a5158740471d167404a84495a74cb2bf7b18944cefb2281af6b29db11fcadbf@[::]:30304
INFO [01-17|12:01:56] IPC endpoint opened: /home/rshi/.ropsten/geth.ipc
INFO [01-17|12:01:56] HTTP endpoint opened: http://localhost:8545
Welcome to the Geth JavaScript console!

instance: Geth/v1.7.2-stable-1db4ecdc/linux-amd64/go1.9
 modules: admin:1.0 debug:1.0 eth:1.0 miner:1.0 net:1.0 personal:1.0 rpc:1.0 txpool:1.0 web3:1.0

> (waited for a long time)
>
> admin.peers
[]
> eth.syncing
false
>
```

Used `--verbosity 5` and confirm that there is no peer connected. Here is a piece of the log:

```
DEBUG[01-17|12:11:39] No discv4 seed nodes found
TRACE[01-17|12:11:39] Dial task done                           task="discovery lookup"
TRACE[01-17|12:11:39] New dial task                            task="dyndial 20c9ad97c081d633 52.169.14.227:30303"
TRACE[01-17|12:11:39] New dial task                            task="discovery lookup"
TRACE[01-17|12:11:39] Dial error                               task="dyndial 20c9ad97c081d633 52.169.14.227:30303" err="dial tcp 52.169.14.227:30303: getsockopt: connection refused"
TRACE[01-17|12:11:39] Dial task done                           task="dyndial 20c9ad97c081d633 52.169.14.227:30303"
TRACE[01-17|12:11:39] Skipping dial candidate                  id=6ce05930c72abc63 addr=13.84.180.240:30303 err="already dialing"
TRACE[01-17|12:11:43] Starting bonding ping/pong               id=20c9ad97c081d633 known=false failcount=0 age=421172h11m43.174491488s
TRACE[01-17|12:11:43] Starting bonding ping/pong               id=6ce05930c72abc63 known=false failcount=0 age=421172h11m43.174543s
TRACE[01-17|12:11:43] >> PING/v4                               addr=52.169.14.227:30303 err=nil
TRACE[01-17|12:11:43] >> PING/v4                               addr=13.84.180.240:30303 err=nil
DEBUG[01-17|12:11:43] No discv4 seed nodes found
TRACE[01-17|12:11:43] Dial task done                           task="discovery lookup"
TRACE[01-17|12:11:43] Skipping dial candidate                  id=20c9ad97c081d633 addr=52.169.14.227:30303 err="recently dialed"
TRACE[01-17|12:11:43] New dial task                            task="discovery lookup"
TRACE[01-17|12:11:47] Starting bonding ping/pong               id=20c9ad97c081d633 known=false failcount=0 age=421172h11m47.176344517s
TRACE[01-17|12:11:47] Starting bonding ping/pong               id=6ce05930c72abc63 known=false failcount=0 age=421172h11m47.176395588s
TRACE[01-17|12:11:47] >> PING/v4                               addr=52.169.14.227:30303 err=nil
TRACE[01-17|12:11:47] >> PING/v4                               addr=13.84.180.240:30303 err=nil
DEBUG[01-17|12:11:47] No discv4 seed nodes found
TRACE[01-17|12:11:47] Dial task done                           task="discovery lookup"
TRACE[01-17|12:11:47] Skipping dial candidate                  id=6ce05930c72abc63 addr=13.84.180.240:30303 err="already dialing"
TRACE[01-17|12:11:47] New dial task                            task="discovery lookup"
TRACE[01-17|12:11:50] Dial error                               task="dyndial 6ce05930c72abc63 13.84.180.240:30303" err="dial tcp 13.84.180.240:30303: i/o timeout"
TRACE[01-17|12:11:50] Dial task done                           task="dyndial 6ce05930c72abc63 13.84.180.240:30303"
TRACE[01-17|12:11:50] Skipping dial candidate                  id=20c9ad97c081d633 addr=52.169.14.227:30303 err="recently dialed"
TRACE[01-17|12:11:51] Starting bonding ping/pong               id=20c9ad97c081d633 known=false failcount=0 age=421172h11m51.176796185s
TRACE[01-17|12:11:51] Starting bonding ping/pong               id=6ce05930c72abc63 known=false failcount=0 age=421172h11m51.176845318s
TRACE[01-17|12:11:51] >> PING/v4                               addr=52.169.14.227:30303 err=nil
TRACE[01-17|12:11:51] >> PING/v4                               addr=13.84.180.240:30303 err=nil
DEBUG[01-17|12:11:51] No discv4 seed nodes found
TRACE[01-17|12:11:51] Dial task done                           task="discovery lookup"
TRACE[01-17|12:11:51] Skipping dial candidate                  id=6ce05930c72abc63 addr=13.84.180.240:30303 err="recently dialed"
TRACE[01-17|12:11:51] New dial task                            task="discovery lookup"
DEBUG[01-17|12:11:52] Recalculated downloader QoS values       rtt=20s confidence=1.000 ttl=1m0s
TRACE[01-17|12:11:55] Starting bonding ping/pong               id=20c9ad97c081d633 known=false failcount=0 age=421172h11m55.175950453s
TRACE[01-17|12:11:55] Starting bonding ping/pong               id=6ce05930c72abc63 known=false failcount=0 age=421172h11m55.175999503s
TRACE[01-17|12:11:55] >> PING/v4                               addr=52.169.14.227:30303 err=nil
TRACE[01-17|12:11:55] >> PING/v4                               addr=13.84.180.240:30303 err=nil
DEBUG[01-17|12:11:55] No discv4 seed nodes found
TRACE[01-17|12:11:55] Dial task done                           task="discovery lookup"
TRACE[01-17|12:11:55] Skipping dial candidate                  id=20c9ad97c081d633 addr=52.169.14.227:30303 err="recently dialed"
TRACE[01-17|12:11:55] New dial task                            task="discovery lookup"
TRACE[01-17|12:11:59] Starting bonding ping/pong               id=20c9ad97c081d633 known=false failcount=0 age=421172h11m59.177396884s
TRACE[01-17|12:11:59] Starting bonding ping/pong               id=6ce05930c72abc63 known=false failcount=0 age=421172h11m59.177462322s
TRACE[01-17|12:11:59] >> PING/v4                               addr=52.169.14.227:30303 err=nil
TRACE[01-17|12:11:59] >> PING/v4                               addr=13.84.180.240:30303 err=nil
DEBUG[01-17|12:11:59] No discv4 seed nodes found
TRACE[01-17|12:11:59] Dial task done                           task="discovery lookup"
TRACE[01-17|12:11:59] Skipping dial candidate                  id=6ce05930c72abc63 addr=13.84.180.240:30303 err="recently dialed"
TRACE[01-17|12:11:59] New dial task                            task="discovery lookup"
```

I checked my firewall and NAT, they allow 30303 and 30304 on both TCP and UDP.

```
$ sudo ufw status | grep 3030
30304                      ALLOW       Anywhere
30303                      ALLOW       Anywhere
30304 (v6)                 ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
30303 (v6)                 ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
$ sudo iptables --list | grep 3030
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:30304
ACCEPT     udp  --  anywhere             anywhere             udp dpt:30304
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:30303
ACCEPT     udp  --  anywhere             anywhere             udp dpt:30303
```

**EDIT**

I also tried to follow [this post](https://github.com/ethereum/ropsten) to strictly set my peers to the revived ropsten net. But the peers still seem to be rejecting my connection.

```
> admin.addPeer('enode://6ce05930c72abc632c58e2e4324f7c7ea478cec0ed4fa2528982cf34483094e9cbc9216e7aa349691242576d552a2a56aaeae426c5303ded677ce455ba1acd9d@13.84.180.240:30303')
TRACE[01-17|13:14:18]                                          msg="sending {\"jsonrpc\":\"2.0\",\"id\":15,\"method\":\"admin_addPeer\",\"params\":[\"enode://6ce05930c72abc632c58e2e4324f7c7ea478cec0ed4fa2528982cf34483094e9cbc9216e7aa349691242576d552a2a56aaeae426c5303ded677ce455ba1acd9d@13.84.180.240:30303\"]}"
TRACE[01-17|13:14:18]                                          msg="<-readResp: response {\"jsonrpc\":\"2.0\",\"id\":15,\"result\":true}"
DEBUG[01-17|13:14:18] Adding static node                       node=enode://6ce05930c72abc632c58e2e4324f7c7ea478cec0ed4fa2528982cf34483094e9cbc9216e7aa349691242576d552a2a56aaeae426c5303ded677ce455ba1acd9d@13.84.180.240:30303
true
> TRACE[01-17|13:14:18] New dial task                            task="staticdial 20c9ad97c081d633 52.169.14.227:30303"
> admin.addPeer('enode://20c9ad97c081d63397d7b685a412227a40e23c8bdc6688c6f37e97cfbc22d2b4d1db1510d8f61e6a8866ad7f0e17c02b14182d37ea7c3c8b9c2683aeb6b733a1@52.169.14.227:30303')
TRACE[01-17|13:14:18]                                          msg="sending {\"jsonrpc\":\"2.0\",\"id\":16,\"method\":\"admin_addPeer\",\"params\":[\"enode://20c9ad97c081d63397d7b685a412227a40e23c8bdc6688c6f37e97cfbc22d2b4d1db1510d8f61e6a8866ad7f0e17c02b14182d37ea7c3c8b9c2683aeb6b733a1@52.169.14.227:30303\"]}"
TRACE[01-17|13:14:18]                                          msg="<-readResp: response {\"jsonrpc\":\"2.0\",\"id\":16,\"result\":true}"
DEBUG[01-17|13:14:18] Adding static node                       node=enode://20c9ad97c081d63397d7b685a412227a40e23c8bdc6688c6f37e97cfbc22d2b4d1db1510d8f61e6a8866ad7f0e17c02b14182d37ea7c3c8b9c2683aeb6b733a1@52.169.14.227:30303
true
> TRACE[01-17|13:14:18] Dial error                               task="staticdial 20c9ad97c081d633 52.169.14.227:30303" err="dial tcp 52.169.14.227:30303: getsockopt: connection refused"
DEBUG[01-17|13:14:18] Can't resolve node                       id=20c9ad97c081d633 err="discovery is disabled"
TRACE[01-17|13:14:18] Dial task done                           task="staticdial 20c9ad97c081d633 52.169.14.227:30303"

>
>
>
>
>
>
> TRACE[01-17|13:14:19] Dial error                               task="staticdial 6ce05930c72abc63 13.84.180.240:30303" err="dial tcp 13.84.180.240:30303: i/o timeout"
DEBUG[01-17|13:14:19] Can't resolve node                       id=6ce05930c72abc63 err="discovery is disabled"
TRACE[01-17|13:14:19] Dial task done                           task="staticdial 6ce05930c72abc63 13.84.180.240:30303"
TRACE[01-17|13:14:19] New dial task                            task="wait for dial hist expire (28.90111341s)"
> DEBUG[01-17|13:14:36] Recalculated downloader QoS values       rtt=20s confidence=1.000 ttl=1m0s
TRACE[01-17|13:14:48] Dial task done                           task="wait for dial hist expire (28.90111341s)"
TRACE[01-17|13:14:48] New dial task                            task="staticdial 20c9ad97c081d633 52.169.14.227:30303"
TRACE[01-17|13:14:48] Dial error                               task="staticdial 20c9ad97c081d633 52.169.14.227:30303" err="dial tcp 52.169.14.227:30303: getsockopt: connection refused"
DEBUG[01-17|13:14:48] Can't resolve node                       id=20c9ad97c081d633 err="discovery is disabled"
TRACE[01-17|13:14:48] Dial task done                           task="staticdial 20c9ad97c081d633 52.169.14.227:30303"
TRACE[01-17|13:14:48] New dial task                            task="wait for dial hist expire (948.889762ms)"
TRACE[01-17|13:14:49] Dial task done                           task="wait for dial hist expire (948.889762ms)"
TRACE[01-17|13:14:49] New dial task                            task="staticdial 6ce05930c72abc63 13.84.180.240:30303"
DEBUG[01-17|13:14:56] Recalculated downloader QoS values       rtt=20s confidence=1.000 ttl=1m0s
TRACE[01-17|13:15:04] Dial error                               task="staticdial 6ce05930c72abc63 13.84.180.240:30303" err="dial tcp 13.84.180.240:30303: i/o timeout"
DEBUG[01-17|13:15:04] Can't resolve node                       id=6ce05930c72abc63 err="discovery is disabled"
TRACE[01-17|13:15:04] Dial task done                           task="staticdial 6ce05930c72abc63 13.84.180.240:30303"
TRACE[01-17|13:15:04] New dial task                            task="wait for dial hist expire (14.050301035s)"
DEBUG[01-17|13:15:16] Recalculated downloader QoS values       rtt=20s confidence=1.000 ttl=1m0s
TRACE[01-17|13:15:18] Dial task done                           task="wait for dial hist expire (14.050301035s)"
TRACE[01-17|13:15:18] New dial task                            task="staticdial 20c9ad97c081d633 52.169.14.227:30303"
TRACE[01-17|13:15:18] Dial error                               task="staticdial 20c9ad97c081d633 52.169.14.227:30303" err="dial tcp 52.169.14.227:30303: getsockopt: connection refused"
DEBUG[01-17|13:15:18] Can't resolve node                       id=20c9ad97c081d633 err="discovery is disabled"
TRACE[01-17|13:15:18] Dial task done                           task="staticdial 20c9ad97c081d633 52.169.14.227:30303"
TRACE[01-17|13:15:18] New dial task                            task="wait for dial hist expire (15.796765988s)"
TRACE[01-17|13:15:34] Dial task done                           task="wait for dial hist expire (15.796765988s)"
TRACE[01-17|13:15:34] New dial task                            task="staticdial 6ce05930c72abc63 13.84.180.240:30303"
DEBUG[01-17|13:15:36] Recalculated downloader QoS values       rtt=20s confidence=1.000 ttl=1m0s
TRACE[01-17|13:15:49] Dial error                               task="staticdial 6ce05930c72abc63 13.84.180.240:30303" err="dial tcp 13.84.180.240:30303: i/o timeout"
DEBUG[01-17|13:15:49] Can't resolve node                       id=6ce05930c72abc63 err="discovery is disabled"
TRACE[01-17|13:15:49] Dial task done                           task="staticdial 6ce05930c72abc63 13.84.180.240:30303"
TRACE[01-17|13:15:49] New dial task                            task="staticdial 20c9ad97c081d633 52.169.14.227:30303"
TRACE[01-17|13:15:50] Dial error                               task="staticdial 20c9ad97c081d633 52.169.14.227:30303" err="dial tcp 52.169.14.227:30303: getsockopt: connection refused"
DEBUG[01-17|13:15:50] Can't resolve node                       id=20c9ad97c081d633 err="discovery is disabled"
TRACE[01-17|13:15:50] Dial task done                           task="staticdial 20c9ad97c081d633 52.169.14.227:30303"
TRACE[01-17|13:15:50] New dial task                            task="wait for dial hist expire (28.843718728s)"
```

Comment: Latest release of geth is v1.7.3, you should try at least that.

Answer (score 7):

**30 Mar 2018** - List of Ropsten peers below updated

---

I used the following commands from [How can I create a list of peers from my syncing geth node to manually paste into my non-syncing geth node using the admin.addPeer() command?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/8828/how-can-i-create-a-list-of-peers-from-my-syncing-geth-node-to-manually-paste-int) to extract a list of peers from my local Ropsten node:

```
function getPeers() {
  admin.peers.forEach( function(e) {
    console.log("admin.addPeer('enode://" + 
      e.id + "@" + 
      e.network.remoteAddress.substring(0, e.network.remoteAddress.indexOf(':')) + 
      ":30303');");
  }) 
}
getPeers();
```

Here is the output of the command:

```
admin.addPeer('enode://7df4f8fa037f82cc03ba0c1acd3fccba4ae40fc03704283979f074cadf37cc5b70845d1acee4161c3432eb6934ba3020cbaf9cc2ba841cdfb03d113ebeef5b79@172.104.5.185:30303');
admin.addPeer('enode://016d3a4627422529a787e6f9258c05f632843a1aded0b25aad84042f36c281211953dcbe62aed342577d9e205177da3f46aa1b22b12eb1236f87ce5bcbeb5a8c@35.227.164.24:30303');
admin.addPeer('enode://09800fa2898bd98da9cc87801a5d3fd391c7b9c035c41c816146a36cb399cb5a7f1e935ffc4607f62946219055cf49db96e4003ac1a318a0f13a4e9f3806d8b2@203.129.29.191:30303');
admin.addPeer('enode://0d51667366489b05c5a9f4980333d6fa93e6f459210d140b69ca1b401c41e2a81215715dae1a01aa4eae96918655ba2777afd4e97affb482bb54051868f0fa90@34.243.198.219:30303');
admin.addPeer('enode://0de6029588e1e90de1e2b78f2369ceedab6f2e2e663942d3edc12c49e64cd981861e906afde234831c5dcbd18901d105cc0e432f5c6ff1310f590ff256907684@174.138.15.5:30303');
admin.addPeer('enode://10c6afe8507aac32d8415a6facdd153647b007b9c1b6ee0f0d6960e215863a4398b66befd40ef87def7de05797db5c8e44d3b6f6f460ea1090f2f048256c496e@194.71.227.15:30303');
admin.addPeer('enode://13595e5320cc95824f39205fcaf6427b2cfd12f27f680e0f05c2aae9c9018b40efdc94bac0c24e74d45f70dcba694bd0f7281066b5b7dbd8877729d3a3606328@144.76.27.80:30303');
admin.addPeer('enode://25e2697e03625a5e34a283caee97998c33356af2cd8605b96bb13e9f40e7caf78ad8115ad81c51a46a885d976aa7a5ee32e38d9bfd9f73b253d1fa6890d51296@195.29.45.126:30303');
admin.addPeer('enode://30b7ab30a01c124a6cceca36863ece12c4f5fa68e3ba9b0b51407ccc002eeed3b3102d20a88f1c1d3c3154e2449317b8ef95090e77b312d5cc39354f86d5d606@52.176.7.10:30303');
admin.addPeer('enode://3dc45adb7f985af1449e275067a8610741a7cad65e22eac399c18a6b46b1edb5cf98a7aa0cd2a446ca197a293a279fbfe65720c65ec7c5fa27eddf3efbb29533@142.4.211.174:30303');
admin.addPeer('enode://4a9f0bd5e5cb38b5726f9eae837e9484228321e4c2c6adedc3bbdeed81f12ca5a8ec1b36f45c7bb8fddfe54882e5aaaf40ce5374c42904f30b788b55b77d6817@212.235.185.131:30303');
admin.addPeer('enode://4cdead890a2dd5b20f0600ff99cbf85a18920cee30de175d55aed4902556705055dbb14a803c2ed9c0cb106e3b9eb0da03b62214bec351ab593603bb5c77f307@52.77.146.201:30303');
admin.addPeer('enode://6991bbef05ca85e9cb0cfab1b8f9427500bb004ff21edb189760d146bf5f37015202b565e0af752f2975f3f8bdc672ab8b39d378b0911874883ac70cdf23c83d@121.122.83.24:30303');
admin.addPeer('enode://81bef4f13cc9d9050438d08361c263ead7c52ab025f905d09b3a87d5ab4e8dd08c5753a42a0fa13a04f81fd2894a1f0b8afe39576889c4bb86434ef928999a49@52.17.29.206:30303');
admin.addPeer('enode://8f909a194e1364534350e5451ba7f3c159723dc06812583e3400161b494430a2f28199fa74624efadfad0eeedce5f84f66651491d482671b9fa2442dace83738@176.9.99.235:30303');
admin.addPeer('enode://b0f7096cee9c97522417d930076e02567aadea87464a4869d84520cec3a28192cc0b3d458fd5825e8ec3c4b12024a0b9628cbfc39bcda9c73d3bdc17a4532608@52.90.217.4:30303');
admin.addPeer('enode://b5fbf355b07c46acb1476746cf2a264c5ebc2931eb87292caa1479b4c172a33d13c15f3f201811ce3e865775c73070b6c939ed425e2ecdf35334d42cd9743cf9@145.239.134.21:30303');
admin.addPeer('enode://bbc5b45054623752444456ac9a397c5ded7649876823835ddfa27583c6c4215f26e8759e034c09ba6c0b54b313530d68f2fe34fbfa44c118301b8701758d206c@113.21.227.203:30303');
admin.addPeer('enode://bd0297e844ec934036015b5a16d46e2a45e52a237e810a31d40908a1323cbfb2ede17f7bff50049c9ffb1740faa5ac54adcb82399fecd1d916bc744d024f4727@13.113.34.20:30303');
admin.addPeer('enode://ce6a3d3f31e85914f6c9a62a1d814c2881b339937c6ee17a1dad00659ea9ab4f2babe1156fa9d145be715b6de43c0dea6096b41d3ad360a3a6311e2dbc42de99@136.243.38.66:30303');
admin.addPeer('enode://d2104a549cb9fc0513ab4f6645008f0ffc56101b4c4956f007710b240ce82193f8f3232e3da2f0ae731ebafbc85466b852b5e71d9f67c849b1b31d95b1f7c1d8@50.23.212.82:30303');
admin.addPeer('enode://ec8c35923e76ce90ada38843fc1483fd74fd59d5a47e71086fed94ab34610de26ea2cfabc933d2c599e895dd5246bb33e479fa0a9b2362065dbf91f0f92c6e59@94.130.35.43:30303');
admin.addPeer('enode://f418aa4f8fb80d9dda99809aa97e10394df5346391360f1f3774d2abab92efecc6043528ad2a2466b751ca3e7d0c0676b80c88eac607edda5886cd05f5dfc9ea@18.217.251.217:30303');
admin.addPeer('enode://f5aabc27285b7469c0b10aea40c866bbb11c53f1b2d44c6c53b6737c04f65ac3c208425e782d228dcc27dfa7e60939c024ba197644ffd80a9d0f7a537387a644@85.233.202.1:30303');
admin.addPeer('enode://f83822f7652b83264e648ede0e08cd37d424184a743331a389409eabed40ed9f746761a98b9dd96fda8167d6b6d58de40c50c496df7895011c756ec0cef8e778@159.89.206.200:30303');
admin.addPeer('enode://fadf0d1dd7d6edd8af52b3b940f729c2b70238ec9a547bf19840564edfa5fbd7bd81233fb5c89560e858f1400b35c3d6c184c34b56c294fdcec7022a8ad9d402@125.227.84.95:30303');
```

You can copy and paste the commands above to manually added these peers to your `geth --testnet console` JavaScript console.

Comment: Thanks the method. However I'm without any syncing ropsten nodes. But good to know the method and up voted.

Answer (score 4):

It seems that the ropsten bootnodes are down for quite a while now. I'm manually adding peers from https://gist.github.com/rfikki/9ebbda396cb8b56543448a7f913828e9 and it works.

Comment: Sorry. Looking at this too late. If it's not too much trouble for you, could you kindly refresh the link?