# Stuck searching for peers, wont update blocks

Tags: wallets, synchronization

I know this has been asked before, but i cannot get my ethereum wallet to sync.  it is stuck at the "ethereum node needs to sync, please wait".  The Test network seems to work and starts downloading the test blocks just fine.

I have little to no experience with commands, so if someone can please explain so an idiot can understand. Thanks!

I am using Mac OSX Yosemite 10.10.5

Ethereeum wallet 0.8.1

Answer (score 2):

There has been some issues with `geth` syncing over the past few days as documented in [geth does not sync out of the box](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/8823/geth-does-not-syncs-out-of-the-box) .

The issue seems to have been resolved with the bootnodes now supplying peer information for `geth` to connect to. You can try running `geth` again and check whether your blocks start synchronising. Note that one of the attacks in the past few days was to make `geth` run slow by executing very high I/O actions in the Ethereum virtual machine. Your `geth` instance should connect to peers but the block processing will be slow.

A new version of `geth` titled **Geth 1.4.13: Into the Woods (various DoS fixes)** has just been released at https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/releases/tag/v1.4.13 . The .zip files have been packaged, but the release binaries are still being built.

Download this new version of `geth` when you find the correct binaries for your system. This version should now sync and process the blocks containing the I/O spam transactions quicker compared to the 1.4.12 version.

If you are unsure about the procedure to separately run this new `geth` version outside the Ethereum Wallet, wait until the new version of `geth` is packaged into a new Ethereum Wallet and released.

---

#### Your GETH log error message

> Last login: Sun Sep 25 21:49:28 on ttys000 Brents-MBP:~ brent$ /Users/brent/Desktop/Ethereum-Wallet.app/Contents/Frameworks/node/geth/geth ; exit; I0925 21:49:34.219133 ethdb/database.go:82] Alloted 128MB cache and 1024 file handles to /Users/brent/Library/Ethereum/chaindata Fatal: Could not open database: resource temporarily unavailable logout

The reason why you get this message is because you have started the Ethereum Wallet and Ethereum Wallet automatically starts an instance of `geth`.

If you want to connect to this `geth` instance, you can issue the command

```
geth attach
```

You can also shut down the Ethereum Wallet which will shut down it's `geth` instance. You can then manually start your own instance of `geth` using the following command

```
geth console
```

You can now start the Ethereum Wallet which will detect that you have manually started your own instance of `geth`, and automatically attach to your instance.

Comment: So when you start geth again after having run `geth --syncmode "fast" --cache 4096` you cannot use `--syncmode "fast"` again? Is it then better to start up a again with `geth --rpc --cache 4096`?